# Need details about EDIV and Rand

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy

Two questions about EDIV and Rand:

1. I need to be sure I understand exactly how EDIV and Rand are used in the BLE Legacy Pairing. What I understood from the Bluetooth specs is that these are generated during the pairing phase by the slave device and exchanged with the master along with the LTK. The part that I am not sure I understood well is how it is used by the slave device during encryption setup. It seems to me that the specs give freedom to the actual BLE implementation about this: either you use EDIV/Rand as a kind of index to retrieve the associated LTK after receiving the encryption request or you re-generate the LTK each time using EDIV/Rand and a device-specific, never shared, secret value. Is that correct?
2. Why have they been removed from Secure Connections pairing? How is the association made between the LTK and the peer device in that case? With the Identity Address?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to be correct about all your thoughts.

**For LE Legacy Pairing**, according to the Bluetooth Core specification, Vol 3 Part H section 2.4.1:

> 4. Encrypted Diversifier (EDIV) is a 16-bit stored value used to identify the LTK distributed during LE legacy pairing. A new EDIV is generated each time a unique LTK is distributed.
> 5. Random Number (Rand) is a 64-bit stored valued used to identify the LTK distributed during LE legacy pairing. A new Rand is generated each time a unique LTK is distributed.

So in the Legacy Pairing the idea is that the EDIV and Random Number pair identifies the LTK that is to be used.

And in section 2.4.2:

> 2.4.2 **Generation of Distributed Keys**
>
> Any method of generation of keys that are being distributed that results in the keys having 128 bits of entropy can be used, as the generation method is not visible outside the slave device (see Section Appendix B). The keys shall not be generated only from information that is distributed to the master device or only from information that is visible outside of the slave device.

So yes you can use any method to generate the EDIV/Rand/LTK values as long as the method provides good security. The specification itself suggests two different method in Vol 3 Part H Appendix B "Key Management":

The first one is that EDIV is an index to a database of LTKs. I suppose here they mean that a new EDIV and LTK pair is generated for each pairing. To me it seems a bit stupid to not use both EDIV and Rand as a lookup key. A variation mentioned is to use `(AES(DHK, Rand) mod 2^16) XOR EDIV` (where DHK is a per device-unique secret key) as index for which I don't get their point either.

The second method is to have per device-unique secret keys DHK and ER. Then for each new pairing you randomly generate 16-bit DIV and 64-bit Rand. EDIV is derived as `(AES(DHK, Rand) mod 2^16) XOR DIV`. The LTK is derived as `AES(ER, DIV)`, which according to me is very stupid compared to simply `AES(ER, Rand || EDIV)` (and let EDIV be randomly generated instead of DIV) since with their method there can only be 2^16 different keys, which when applying the Birthday Paradox means that after around 256 generated keys there will probably be duplicates. (If anyone in the Bluetooth SIG is reading this - please tell me the reason for this weird method). Anyway by deriving LTK from EDIV and Rand you don't need to store the LTK nor the EDIV/Rand values. A thing they seem to have forgot about is that since a different key size (7-16 bytes) may be negotiated during the pairing, you must still for each bonded device store the key size the resulting key should be truncated to upon further encryptions. Or you can workaround this by for example hardcoding some 4 bits in the Rand value which key size to be used.

There is one issue with simply ignoring having a security database at all and just rely on that the LTK can always be recovered from the master's EDIV and Rand: you will never be able to "remove" the bond or revoke the key. Also, if you strictly follow GAP you should know whether you have a usable key to start encryption for a current connection. For example, when responding with an error when reading a GATT characteristic because the characteristic requires an encrypted link, there are different error codes depending on if an LTK is available or not; "Insufficient Encryption" if LTK is available and "Insufficient Authentication" if not.

**In LE Secure Connections**, the LTK is not distributed but *contributed*, which means it's derived from values from both peers (using a Diffie Hellman function as the core). Therefore one part cannot select the LTK freely. The input values to the LTK generation function are the Diffie Hellman shared secret, random nonces from both peers and the Bluetooth Device Addresses of both peers (the address used in the connection, not the Identity Address). Since the input values take up more space than LTK, it's more feasible to just store the LTK in a database.

Since there must be exactly one LTK per bonded device there is no more any point in having EDIV and Rand so they shall be set to 0 in encryption requests. That means we must also now map device to LTK rather than EDIV/Rand to LTK. To do that the Identity Address is used when looking up the LTK. If a random resolvable address is used for a connection we must test all stored IRKs and get the corresponding Identity Address. If public or static random address is used for a connection - that is the Identity Address.

Comment: Excellent explanation. I'm kind of confuse the term Device Address and Identity Address in BLE spec. According to your description, it seems Device Address corresponds to Public Address and Random Static Address. Identity Address corresponds to Random Resolvable Private Address, am I right?

Comment: Device Address is whatever address used for establing the connection. Identity Address must be either a Public Address or Random Static address. If "privacy" feature (i.e. using random resolvable addresses) is turned off, then the Device Address will be equal to the Identity Address. If "privacy" is permanently turned on, then the Identity Address is quite meaningless and only serves as some kind of identifier that may be used for stack-internal purposes.